# SignalR refusing connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to configure my signalR demo to my project

**framework : 4.0** ,
**SignalR version : 1.1.3**

Here's my code

```
$(function () {
            var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:32555/');
            var chat = connection.createHubProxy('myChatHub');
            chat.on('send', function (message) {
                $('#chat').html($('#chat').html() + "\r\n" + message);
            });
            connection.logging = true;
            connection.start().done(function () {
                alert("Connection Complete");
                $('#sendBtn').click(function () {
                    chat.invoke('send', $('#message').val());
                });
            }).fail(function (param) {
                console.log(param);
            });
        });
```

Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
        }
```

.Cs

```
namespace vPortal
{
    [HubName("myChatHub")]
    public class LetsChat : Hub
    {
        public void send(string message,string userid,string Name)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message, userid, Name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to run the page I got this error

```
SignalR: Error during negotiation request:
```

But, I have enabled proxy in the **global.asax** I have tried upgrading my signalR to version **2.2.3**.
But, my project packages are incompatible with the current version so I installed version 1.1.3.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here I see there is a connection but can not establish.

Comment: why you enabled  EnableCrossDomain = true ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I have seen somewhere that they have disabled crossdomain by default from the 1.1.3

Comment: so you want to enable cross domain request for you application? also i want to know how you included the script files in your application for signalR

Comment: @FrebinFrancis no, but i was just testing but if you disable CORS then also I'm getting the same error this one 
SignalR: Incompatible protocol version

Comment: Please see this link to get an idea about how to use signalR 1X in application. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: @FrebinFrancis thanks will take a look and will tell you

Comment: ok. please refer the link carefully. any doubts you can ask.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Upgraded still failed my project preferences are in 4.0 somehow I'm unable to detect the problem `Uncaught Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection has started.` getting this error now

Comment: ok please post your current javascript code.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9974067 its too big

Comment: You see this function in the mentioned link  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { alert('connection ok'); } please put your $(".send").click function inside of this done callback, and also do an alert so that you can verify that the connection is established. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: @FrebinFrancis doing the same but its showing error. I'm trying to downgrade now signalR to 1.1.4

Comment: which version are you using now ? and are you using ASP.NET web forms or MVC ?

Comment: and which version of SignalR ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis 1.1.4

Comment: I just created an application in ASP.NET web forms and it works prefectly.i think you missed something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71466/discussion-between-just-code-and-frebin-francis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lots of credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4519336/frebin-francis) man.
he made my problem easy to solve.

See, first of all my all the references were to **4.0** then So I used Signalr Older version 1.1.4

Here's is my errors scenario:

1. **SignalR could not connect**:
   I removed this error by adding the lines  `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` in my Global.asax file.
2. **Negotiation of request**: There was a silly mistake done by me the **namespace** was different in the my chat.aspx page.
3. **Version Conflicts:** See, I got previous libraries which were incompatible with the current version (2.3.2) of signalR. So, I had to stick to previous version of it (1.1.3) the steps are given [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and its pretty neat.

Again,I was pretty sure about my code signalR will work fine:

So, run my **chat** and my first message was succeed then Again there was an error after sometime and the error was

```
the added or subtracted value results in an un-representable datetime. signlar
```

So, this was the big headache for me.This is definately nothing do with the signalR
I got the clue from frebin and I realized that in my web.config

```
 <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" maxRequestLength="512000" />
```

The executionTimeout previous value was **9999999999**

i changed to 180 and its works fine!!!

I have added all the scenarios for the future preferences.